# mySQL output to XML error

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I want to show my database in XML if the API-key is correctly. 
Everything works fine until the XML page should show up.
It shows this error:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 3 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

My code:

```
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM WKplayers";
            $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

            $xml = new XMLWriter();

            $xml->openURI("php://output");
            $xml->startDocument();
            $xml->setIndent(true);
            $xml->startElement('Players');

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
              $xml->startElement("Player");
                $xml->startElement("Name");
                 $xml->writeRaw($row['Player']);
                 $xml->endElement();
              $xml->endElement();
            }

            $xml->endElement();

            header('Content-type: text/xml');
            $xml->endDocument();  
            $xml->flush();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find it necessary in your context to use writeraw, simply use the row value as second argument to startElement as

```
$xml->startElement("Player",$row['Player']);
```

and don't forget to close document by

```
$xml->endDocument();
```

before

```
$xml->flush();
```

Comment: how do you want to display your player values? as separate value or as attribute value of Player tag?

Comment: Like this:

<Players>
  <Player>Codeek</Player>
  <Country>Germany</Country>
</Players

Comment: Hi it didn't work but I've changed some things (like removing $con, from fetch_assoc, but right now it just shows all the names from the database without the XML structure any idea what's wrong? I'll update my new code.

Comment: Nvm forgot to click on " Show source code command ", thanks anyway :).

Comment: Well good to hear you found your solution. thnx for the answer mark, but you shouldn't have done it if didn't help you :), nvm. happy coding